# recorrer una enumeracion con for c#

Tags: c#, bucle-for, enum

Como puedo recorrer una enumeracion con un ciclo for en c#?
Quiero usar la variable de la enumeracion para recorrerlo pero no se como convertirla
Hasta ahora tengo esto con errores:

```
**namespace Menu_CS
{

    enum Menu
    {
        Alta,
        Baja,
        Modificacion
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Menu de opciones: ");

            Menu opcion;

            for ( opcion = 0; opcion <= 2; opcion++)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}) {1}", opcion.GetHashCode, opcion.ToString());
        }
    }
}**
```

Comment: Saludos. Da un vistazo a https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/how-to-enumerate-an-enum

Comment: hola podrias hacerme saber si te sirvio la respuesta dada

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que castear prueba con esto

```
for(int i = 0; i<=2; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine( ((Menu)i).ToString();
 }
```

El Casteo es la parte ((Menu)i).ToString()

En caso de que tengas c# 6 o superior pues la cosa es más fácil
Sería

```
string sEnum = nameof(MiEnum.ValorEnum);
```

Siguiendo tu ejemplo sería

```
string opción = nameof(Menu.Alta);
```

Imprimiría "Alta"

Aunque para este caso específico es mejor lo primero que te explico del casteo

Comment: Hola te sirvio esta solucion? podrias hacermelo saber, gracias

Answer (score -1):

Esta seria otra posible forma de resolverlo:

```
class Program
{
    enum Menu
    {
        Alta,
        Baja,
        Modificacion
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Menu opcion;

        Console.WriteLine("Menu de opciones: ");
        
        List<Menu> lista = new List<Menu>();

        foreach (Menu nom in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Program.Menu)))
        {
            lista.Add(nom);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}) {1}", lista[i].GetHashCode(), lista[i].ToString());
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Que tal si leyendo [answer], editas y explicas tu código